# What exactly does TRegTypes.RegisterType() do?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When I use Java2OP, I see that it adds the following at the end of the generated file:

```
procedure RegisterTypes;
begin
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('JavaInterfaces.JAnimator', TypeInfo(JavaInterfaces.JAnimator));
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('JavaInterfaces.JAnimator_AnimatorListener', TypeInfo(JavaInterfaces.JAnimator_AnimatorListener));
  ....
end;
```

What is the purpose of this? What does `TRegTypes.RegisterType()` actually do?